# How to select a button in react via css class

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to select a button that is getting rendered dynamically (where I do not have any control) into a div (adyen_google_container). I would like to select the button and click the button. As this button is rendered dynamically I could not attach a ref to the button.

```
const AdyenGooglePay = (): JSX.Element => {

const [showButton, setShowButton] = useState<boolean>(false);

const mountGooglePay = async () => {
// logic to mount the component to adyen-google-container 
};

useEffect(() => {
    if (dependent_variable) {
      mountGooglePay();
      return;
    }

    setShowButton(false);
  }, [dependent_variable]);

  return <div id="adyen-google-container"/>
};
```

The following is the rendered output.

```
<div id="adyen-google-container">
   <span class="adyen-checkout__paywithgoogle">
      <div class="gpay-card-info-container-fill">
         <button type="button" aria-label="Google Pay" class="gpay-card-info-container black long en">
         </button>
      </div>
   </span>
</div>
```

I would be much obliged if I could know how I can programatically click the button element?

Comment: too few info. How is your component, classes, functional, what have you tried? Have yoy checked out React components for Google Pay buttons like this one? https://github.com/google-pay/google-pay-button

Comment: you can use document.getElementById("adyen_google_container").click().

Comment: Thanks, I have elaborated the question more, also I'm unable to use google's pay button and have to use a third-party-provided one.

Comment: try what @AbhilashCR said, in a useEffect. Check if exists, if is already in the DOM firt, then get the element by Id as the comment

Comment: Thanks I was able to resolve it through the above replies:
const element: HTMLElement = document.getElementsByClassName('gpay-card-info-container black long en')[0] as HTMLElement;
        element.click();